# Hi lo poker. Low hand ties

Tags: rules, poker-theory, omaha-hi-lo

What happens in hi lo when there is a tie for the best hand hi and lo?

I was playing recently and went all in with another player and we both had the exact same hand, A2345.

I was told that I lose because the other player had a 6. I thought we split because you only play the best 5 cards.

Comment: Can you tell us the cards you had, the cards your friend had and the table cards to be sure I answered you well, or edit my answer acording to the exact situation?

Answer (score 3):

At Omaha Hi/Lo, if someone has a low hand (five cards bellow 8), the pot divides.

If you both have A2345, you had the lowest possible hand, so you have to divide the low part of the pot, 1/4 for each player.

I suspect you thought you also tie for the highest hand, but if your opponent have a 6 he probably had 23456 as high hand, which beats A2345. So your opponent got 3/4 of the pot and you only recover 1/4.